# How to get Particular Object(table) or Column(field) from DB

Tags: hibernate, web-services, openbravo

```
final Product product = OBDal.getInstance().get(Product.class, productID); //got productID using getParameter from url passed by user

if (product == null) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product with id: " + productID + " does not exist");
}


// select lines from C_ORDERLINE table that match the product
final OBCriteria<OrderLine> orderLineList = OBDal.getInstance().createCriteria(OrderLine.class);
orderLineList.add(Restrictions.eq(OrderLine.PROPERTY_PRODUCT, product));//adds object which are equals(product from DB with given product)
final List<BaseOBObject> orders = new ArrayList<BaseOBObject>();




// iterate through the lines
for (OrderLine orderLine : orderLineList.list()) {
  // get the order and only add each order once
  if (!orders.contains(orderLine.getSalesOrder())) {
    orders.add(orderLine.getSalesOrder());  // this adds  SalesOrder(i.e C_Orderline table) object in List<BaseOBObject> 
  }
}
```

Code source : [Openbravo Webservice code][1]

I'm trying to create webservice in Openbravo.

Above is working fine but I'm unable to understand fetching of above table(object ) using getSalesOrder because there is no column(Primary key) name SalesOrder in C_Orderline

Well i have basic knowledge of mapping object and table mapping.

Question: Why getSalesOrder() is used to get object(table-C_Orderline) even though there is not tablename SalesOrder ?

Also i need to know how to get particular column of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering you guys

Well I was having doubt that there should be a getter method called getOrderLine() which gives OrderLine Object(Table) so what i did is i decompile OrderLine.class file to make it sure what i found was OrderLine object was mapped with mehod called getSalesOrder() which gives OrderLine Object.

Thanks for your time.